# NSMutableArray can't add object from JSONModelArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a NSMutableArray and adding objects to it as below:

```
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[array addObject:@"Apple"];

[array addObject:@"Orange"];

[array addObject:@"Mango"];

[array addObject:@"Banana"];
```

But when I try to add object from JSONModelArray still showing the above 4 object only.

Here is JSONModelArray code:

```
//fetch the feed
_collectionBusinessFeeds = [[CollectionBusinessManager alloc] initFromURLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/json/collectionBusinessFinal.json"
                           completion:^(JSONModel *model, JSONModelError *err) {


                               for(NSDictionary *item in _collectionBusinessFeeds.collectionBusinesses){
                                   NSLog(@"%@",item);
                                   NSString *title = [item valueForKey:@"name"];

                                   [array addObject:title];

                                   NSLog(@"%@",array);
  // here array is printing all the objects with the above 4 objects

                               }

                          }];
```

But return array here below only showing above 4 objects not the all the objects added from JSONModelArray.

```
-(NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return [array count];
// only showing 4 above obects like Apple, Banana...
}
```

Here is my full implementation file:

```
    #import "CollectionViewController.h"
#import "AccordionViewController.h"

#import "JSONModelLib.h"
#import "CollectionBusinessManager.h"
#import "HUD.h"

@interface CollectionViewController (){

    CollectionBusinessManager* _collectionBusinessFeeds;
}

@end

@implementation CollectionViewController

NSMutableArray* array;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [array addObject:@"Apple"];

    [array addObject:@"Orange"];

    [array addObject:@"Mango"];

    [array addObject:@"Banana"];

    //show loader view

    [HUD showUIBlockingIndicatorWithText:@"Fetching JSON"];

    //fetch the feed
    _collectionBusinessFeeds = [[CollectionBusinessManager alloc] initFromURLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/json/collectionBusinessFinal.json"
                               completion:^(JSONModel *model, JSONModelError *err) {
                                //hide the loader view
                                [HUD hideUIBlockingIndicator];

                                   [self.v reloadData];

                                   NSLog(@"%@", _collectionBusinessFeeds.collectionBusinesses);
                                   for(NSDictionary *item in _collectionBusinessFeeds.collectionBusinesses){
                                       NSLog(@"%@",item);
                                       NSString *title = [item valueForKey:@"name"];

                                       [array addObject:[title copy]];

                                       NSLog(@"%@",array);

                                   }

                              }];




}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}





#pragma mark collection view methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {

    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [array count];
}


- (UIColor*) randomColor{
    int r = arc4random() % 255;
    int g = arc4random() % 255;
    int b = arc4random() % 255;
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:1];
}


-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:100];
    label.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.backgroundColor = [self randomColor];

    return cell;


}


-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    AccordionViewController *detailVC = [[AccordionViewController alloc] init];
    detailVC.passParam= [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailVC.title = detailVC.passParam;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
}





/*


 #pragma mark - Navigation





 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation


 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {


 // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].


 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.


 }


 */
```

@end

can anybody help me?

**Update:**
at last it solved my problem adding the property like below:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
```

[self.collectionView reloadData];

Comment: Ohh your collection view delegate method calling before adding other object to array. please reload collection view once new object added in array [<collectionView> reloadData].

Comment: I have checked the dictionary and jsonmodelarray printing the log and jsonmodelarray already have 10 items and also nsdictionary also have 10 items and all the items adding into the array but when return count only showing 4 but it should 14 items.

Comment: I tried to add [self.collectionView reloadData]; and also [array addObject:[title copy]]; both but still have the same problem though [self.collectionView reloadData]; showing not found error because I have added collectionview into a view controller.

Comment: use the [tableView reloadData]; at the end of completion: ^

Comment: Did you define your array as __block before NSMutableArray *array?

Answer (score 0):

```
//fetch the feed
_collectionBusinessFeeds = [[CollectionBusinessManager alloc] initFromURLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/json/collectionBusinessFinal.json"
                           completion:^(JSONModel *model, JSONModelError *err) {


                               for(NSDictionary *item in _collectionBusinessFeeds.collectionBusinesses){
                                   NSLog(@"%@",item);
                                   NSString *title = [item valueForKey:@"name"];

                                   [array addObject:title];

                                   [collectionView reloadData];

                                   NSLog(@"%@",array);

                               }

                          }];
I have edited code, please check above code.
```

Comment: [collectionView reloadData]; showing me not found error because I have added collectionView into a UIViewController so what should I reload there then?

Comment: Either you have the collectionView programmatically created, or in a property extended from the storyboard, use the name you have on that property instead collectionView.

Comment: I have set now bcBoard as identity Restoration ID for UICollectionView now how can I access it from the UIViewController implementation file? Because I am new to IOS.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are describing, it seems like the fetch is being called after the collection view has calculated the number of items. You have to reload the collection view after fetching your new results.

Comment: How can you say that fetch is being called after the collection view has calculated the number of items?
It can be possible 4 object manually added in viewDidLoad and then trying to add other objects.

Comment: Well, it's exactly the same answer that you gave. If he's fetching the values from a server, he's probably using an async call. That means that the collectionView is calculating the number of items to display based on the ones that are added into the array at that moment (4). Once fetched and added the new items into the array, he needs to reload the collectionView so it calculates again the number of items to display.

Comment: Thats what i want to say..cheer:)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

```
    #import "CollectionViewController.h"
    #import "AccordionViewController.h"

    #import "JSONModelLib.h"
    #import "CollectionBusinessManager.h"
    #import "HUD.h"

    @interface CollectionViewController (){

        CollectionBusinessManager* _collectionBusinessFeeds;
    }
    @property (nonatommic, strong) NSMutableArray *array;
    @end

    @implementation CollectionViewController


    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self.array addObject:@"Apple"];

        [self.array addObject:@"Orange"];

        [self.array addObject:@"Mango"];

        [self.array addObject:@"Banana"];

        But when I try to add object from JSONModelArray still showing the above 4 object only.

        Here is JSONModelArray code:

        //fetch the feed
        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        _collectionBusinessFeeds = [[CollectionBusinessManager alloc]                                            initFromURLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/json/collectionBusinessFinal.json"
                               completion:^(JSONModel *model, JSONModelError *err) {


                           for(NSDictionary *item in _collectionBusinessFeeds.collectionBusinesses){
                               NSLog(@"%@",item);
                               NSString *title = [item valueForKey:@"name"];

                               [weakSelf.array addObject:title];

                               NSLog(@"%@", weakSelf.array);
  // here array is printing all the objects with the above 4 objects

                           }

                      }];
```

**Old Answer**
            If you add __block to your array initialisation it must works.

```
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        __block NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [array addObject:@"Apple"];

        [array addObject:@"Orange"];

        [array addObject:@"Mango"];

        [array addObject:@"Banana"];

    But when I try to add object from JSONModelArray still showing the above 4 object only.

        Here is JSONModelArray code:

        //fetch the feed
        _collectionBusinessFeeds = [[CollectionBusinessManager alloc]                                            initFromURLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/json/collectionBusinessFinal.json"
                               completion:^(JSONModel *model, JSONModelError *err) {


                           for(NSDictionary *item in _collectionBusinessFeeds.collectionBusinesses){
                               NSLog(@"%@",item);
                               NSString *title = [item valueForKey:@"name"];

                               [array addObject:title];

                               NSLog(@"%@",array);
  // here array is printing all the objects with the above 4 objects

                           }

                      }];
```

Comment: well I have added code below __block NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; but now nothing is showing on the screen.

Comment: change your array definition. use @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array; and use a weak reference of self inside of your block. __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self; I will update my answer

Comment: so the count return should be return [self.array count]; right? I have updated your code but still have the same problem though I have added property collectionView and reload there but still have the same problem.

Comment: but still showing the 4 items instead of 14 items there.

Comment: I recommend you to do this. Firstly change the name to array, it's not a good practice to use array as name of an array, maybe arrayFruits in your case. Second add [weakSelf.arrayFruits addObject:@"watermelon"]; in your block before [array addObject:title];. Add a breakpoint in your line NSLog(@"%@",array); and check in the Variables View if arrayFruits is a NSMutableArray object and it's content